# http or https <image> component on React Native showing blank on Android 4.1.2 (API 16)

Tags: android, image, react-native, components

Hello I'm just a newbie on react native.

I'm trying to use a Facebook tutorial for the image component

```html
export default class PropertyFinder extends Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
     uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
    };
    var yourPicture = require ('./images/image1.jpg');
    return (
     <ScrollView>
        <Image source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/UePbdph.jpg'}} style={{width: 200, height: 227}} />
        <Text> test </Text>
         <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
         <Image source={yourPicture}/>
         <View>
         <Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}} style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
         </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

I ran this on the AVD emulator and **it works all the images show**

But, I tried to debug on the device (old lenovo API 16) and an image is shown only for the local image **var yourPicture** , all the URI http / https images aren't showing. They are just blank.

So I'm curious, how can this be happening?

I've tried to search the forum, but can't found any solution. I also tried to release the apk, and install it on my old lenovo, but I still get the same result. (only local image shows)

Finally I tried to install it on my new xiaomi (android 6), and all the images show..

Hmm this behavior is odd, because React native supports android 16, right?

**minSdkVersion 16**

Any way to fix this?

Thank you very much......

Comment: Please connect your device and run `adb logcat` - there may be something in the Android logs that could assist.

Comment: Be aware that android 4.1.2 by default only supports TLS 1.0 for https. I would think that the image fetching on https throws an exception and causes this behavior. Github uses TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using big images?

You should try to use `android:largeheap="true"` to see if it's works with that. If the image appear than mean you have a memory issue on old devices.

`android:largeheap="true"` is not a solution. It should be only used for apps which require a lot of memory (like drawing on picture).

You can use [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) to reduce the size of your files